# How to show and change user in Scheduled Queries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Some of the scheduled queries in Google Cloud Platform suddenly don't run anymore, with the message "Access Denied: ... User does not have bigquery.tables.get permission for table..."

First, is it possible to see under which user the scheduled query is running?
Second, is it possible to change the user?

Thanks, Silvan

Comment: Have you gone through the scheduling docs in detail? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

Comment: I've realized now from the docs that the CLI offers some more options. I've tried with `bq show --transfer_config projects/...`, which shows me the userId. But now I try to figure out how to get the user from the userId...

Comment: @Silvan, can you elaborate a little bit more what is the problem you are having now?

Comment: @Alexandre, I'd like to see the user with which a scheduled query is running. With CLI I can do a `bq show --transfer_config ...`, where I can see a userId. It is only a number, and does not even correspond with the "Unique ID" shown in the Web UI, in Service account details. So for existing scheduled queries I don't know the user. But ok, I'll change the user for all queries to a service account...

Comment: I reviewing the documentation to check if it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I always use service accounts for command line execution...

if you can use bq cli, look at --service_account and --service_account_credential_file

If you still want to use the schedule query, there is some documentation on the service account on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries (per above)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I could change the user for the scheduled query to a service account with `bq update --transfer_config --update_credentials --service_account_name=... projects/...` So this one solved, it's still a mystery with finding out the userId. The userId shown from `bq show ...` is a bit cryptic.

Comment: Agree, there seems to be no way to determine what SA or user is running a query, neither through console or bq cli.

Answer (score 2):

Although this thread is 2 years old, it is still relevant. So I will guide you on how to troubleshoot this issue below:

**Cause**:
This issue happens when the user that was running the query does not meet the required permissions. This could have been caused by a permissions removal or update of the scheduled query's user.

**Step 1 - Checking which user is running the query**:
Head to GCP - BigQuery - Scheduled Queries

Once on the scheduled queries screen, click on the display name of the query that need to be checked and head to configuration. There you will find the user that currently runs the query.

**Step 2 - Understanding the permissions that are needed for running the query**:
As specified on [Google Cloud's website](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#required_permissions) you need 3 permissions:
[bigquery.transfers.update, and, on the dataset: bigquery.datasets.get and bigquery.datasets.update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ztf.png)

**Step 3 - Check running user's permissions**:
From the GCP menu head to IAM & Admin - IAM

[IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh9LJ.png)

There you will find the permissions assigned to different users. Verify the permissions possessed by the user running the query.

Now we can solve this issue in 2 different ways:

**Step 4 - Edit current user's roles *or* update the scheduler's credentials with an email that has the required permissions**:

- Option 1: Edit current user's roles: On the IAM screen you can click on "Edit
  principal" next to a user to add, remove or update roles (remember to
  add a role that complies with the permissions required mentioned in
  Step 2).
- Option 2: Update credentials (as @coderintherye suggested in another
  answer):      Head to GCP - BigQuery - Scheduled Queries and select
  the query you      want to troubleshoot - Head to MORE (on the
  top-right corner of the      screen) - Update credentials - Finally,
  choose a mail. **WARNING**: That mail will    now be the user that
  runs the query, so make sure that it has the       permissions needed
  as mentioned in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done (for a normal non-service account user) via the console as per the instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#update_scheduled_query_credentials

"To refresh the existing credentials on a scheduled query:
Find and view the status of a scheduled query.
Click the MORE button and select Update credentials."

[image: Screenshot of bigquery instructions]

Answer (score 1):

To change a scheduled query from a user to a service account, you need to:

1. make sure that the service account is from the same project as the project where you are running your scheduled query.
2. You as a user and the service account, should have the appropriate permissions:
   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions
3. You can run a command from the CLI or python code to make the change from user to service account:

CLI:

```
bq update \
--transfer_config \
--update_credentials \
--service_account_name=abcdef-test-sa@abcdef-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
projects/862514312345/locations/us/transferConfigs/5dd12f12-0000-122f-bc38-089e0820fe38
```

Python:

```sql
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2

transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

service_account_name = "email address of your service account"
transfer_config_name = "projects/SOME_NUMBER/locations/EUROPE_OR_US/transferConfigs/A_LONG_ALPHANUMERIC_ID"

transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(name=transfer_config_name)

transfer_config = transfer_client.update_transfer_config(
    {
        "transfer_config": transfer_config,
        "update_mask": field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=["service_account_name"]),
        "service_account_name": service_account_name,
    }
)

print("Updated config: '{}'".format(transfer_config.name))
```

See also here for code examples:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#update_scheduled_query_credentials

Comment: Thank you, I had been struggling with the python approach as the service account I was authenticating with didn't have the requisite permissions, I tried to add  big query admin permissions and still couldn't get it to go through.  I'm sure I missed something.

But the CLI approach worked like a charm as I didn't run into permission issues.

Comment: Thank you for that! Do you happen to know to whom this will send any notifications in the event of failure?

Answer (score 0):

```
bq update --transfer_config --update_credentials  --service_account_name=<service_accounnt> <resource_name>
```

service account = service account id that you wish to use as a credential.
resource_name = resource name of the Scheduled query that you can see in the configuration section of the Scheduled query detail page.

Comment: Would I need to be authenticated in the service account or authenticated with the owner of the scheduled query account?